# Python: How do I export a single object as a .dae file?

Tags: python, dae

I need to be able to export multiple .dae files from a single .blend but I'm not sure about the process of doing this. Is it possible? When I export the .dae manually, it exports all the objects in the .blend not simply the one I selected.

Answer (score 1):

To do it manually :

In **Object mode** with the object(s) selected

**File** > **Export** > **Collada (.dae)**

On the lower left hand side of the Collada export window you will find the export options, check the **Selection Only** option before exporting

[image]

Hope this helps a little.